# When converting a UTC formatted string to Unix time_t, what are the time stamp and seconds in the day actually doing?

Tags: c++, string, time, unix-timestamp, utc

Here is the piece of code I mean:

```
COleDateTime dateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
time_t timeT = ((double)dateTime * 86400) - 2209161600;
```

86400 is the number of seconds in the day and 2209161600 is a time stamp for 3rd Jan 2040 00:00:00.

Why are these numbers part of the calculation, as while there is explanations on using this piece of code there is no information on WHY its being used. This is an example of a website that tells you to use this when doing this conversion, but has no explanation as to why: http://mfctips.com/2013/01/28/convert-utc-formatted-string-to-unix-time_t-or-ctime/

Any help/explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: [time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t): "Although not defined, this is almost always an integral value holding the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC, corresponding to  POSIX time. "

Comment: This doesn't actually explain why I'm using those values.

Answer (score 2):

2209161600 is ~70 years - a time duration, not a time point.

`COleDateTime` has a different epoch which starts in year ~1900, whereas Unix epoch starts in year 1970.

Hence, to go from duration since 1900 to duration since 1970 you need to subtract from the duration 70 years.

---

You could just use standard [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) function to convert from a broken down local time representation to `time_t`. Or `timegm` to convert from a broken down UTC time representation.